# Can someone identify this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Could someone help identify what font is used in these screenshots? Thanks.

http://zshthem.es/all/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this font is Menlo from the Mac Terminal hence why all the terminal code is in the screen shots:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menlo_(typeface)

Can be found here:
http://trilliumprints.com/Font/M/menlo-font.html